# DynamicRouteValueTransformer.TransformAsync invoked many times

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to handle dynamic routes. Like: `example.com/ahqwehqw`

I'm also have default routes like `/Home/Index`

I have something like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SeoTransformer>("{**path}");
});
```

Problems:

1. TransformAsync is being called when I ask for an existing routes (`/Home/Index`)
2. TransformAsync also is being called more than once when client requests something from `/wwwroot`

Answer (score 0):

You may not use `app.UseStaticFiles()`. In this case, access `/home/index`, the default map route will respond.

But there may be CSS and JavaScript links in the view `Index` . These links were originally parsed by `UseStaticFiles`. But there is no `UseStaticFiles` now.

At this time, the default map route does not match these links. So they will be mapped to `SeoTransformer`, which is the reason for multiple calling.

Comment: @rmk, can accept this answer, or do you have any other issues?